# javascript get rest of text where cursor is placed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

How can I get the rest of left or right side text in a `contenteditable` div, based on where my cursor is placed?

[image]

Comment: Start with posting some code, preferably post a fiddle as well, so we can see what you're doing, what the issue is, and what you've done to try and figure it out for yourself ?

Comment: just text, or do you need all the sub-tags and stuff too?

Comment: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/713x210q90/837/z2mq.jpg maybe this explains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get the content both to the right and left of the cursor. It hasn't been tested with line-breaks, tags or anything else that might be in an editable div, but it is a function that I have used before.

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/Dez48/

```
function getCursorPosition(editableDiv) {
    var cursorPos = 0,
        containerEl = null,
        sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
                cursorPos = range.endOffset;
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
            var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
            editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
            var tempRange = range.duplicate();
            tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
            tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
            cursorPos = tempRange.text.length;
        }
    }
    return cursorPos;
}

$('#content').on('click', function () {
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    var cursor = getCursorPosition(this);
    $('#left').text(currentText.substring(0, cursor));
    $('#right').text(currentText.substring(cursor));

});
```